# Как ответить на сообщение пользователя, после конкретного события

Tags: telebot, бот

Задумка: После /start пользователю показывается меню из reply кнопок, если он пишет какой-то текст(не названия reply кнопок), то бот отвечает:’Выберите что-то из меню’. Если человек нажимает на кнопку, допустим «Написать отзыв», то человек отправляет какое-то сообщение и вот как сделать так, чтобы бот в данном случае отвечал не ‘Выберите что-то из меню’, а другой текст?(библиотека Telebot)

Comment: `telebot` который на node.js, или `telebot` тот, что pyTelegramBotAPI (то-есть для пайтон)? Нужно обязательно уточнять язык программирования и библиотеку.

Comment: используй fsm, при нажатии на кнопку, в хендлере пропиши стейт, что бы бот ждал сообщения от пользователя. Затем обрабатывай это сообщение каким-то образом

Comment: который для пайтон

Answer (score 1):

Сделай новую функцию которая будет обрабатывать сообщение

```
def func(message):
    pass
```

А в хендлере:

```
if message.text == "Написать отзыв":
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, func)
```

Так ты скажешь что бы func был следующим хендлером и он обрабатывал сообщение после того как пользователь сказал "Написать отзыв"